# How to get depth in depth xml value in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have below xml file , have id and value . Need result of field_name =test2 with id 3

```
    <Types>
<Type field_name="Test1">
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <value>A</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <value>B</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>3</id>
            <value>C</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
            <value>D</value>
        </item>
    </items>
    </Type>
    <Type field_name="Test2">
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <value>A</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <value>B</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>3</id>
            <value>C</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
            <value>D</value>
        </item>
    </items>
    </Type>
</Types>
```

I needs to get  result by **id** with field_name =test2   , I had tried below code but no luck.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Test.xml")
$xml.types.type.items.item | ? {$_.id -eq 3} | select value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bash
# This is a more robust way to load an XML file (PSv5+).
# In earlier versions, use ($xml = New-Object xml)...
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path C:\Test.xml))

# PSv4+ syntax
@($xml.types.type.Where({ $_.'field_name' -eq 'Test2' }, 'First').
  items).ForEach({ $_.item }).Where({ $_.id -eq 3 }).value
```

Note the use of the PSv4+ [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) and [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) array methods for filtering and enumeration, and, specifically, the need to explicitly enumerate the `<item>` child elements with `.ForEach()` (see bottom section).

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, since the `.Where()` call only returns a *single* object that has only a *single* `items` child element, the `.ForEach()` isn't strictly necessary in *this* case, but in your original code it is.

Also note the use of `@(...)`, which is only necessary in *Windows PowerShell*, due to a bug that has since been fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*</sup>

---

However, it's **easier to use an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query**, which, in combination with [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml), enables a single-command solution:

```bash
(Select-Xml '//Type[@field_name="Test2"]/items/item[id=3]' C:\Test.xml).Node.value
```

Note:

- If your XML document uses *namespaces*, you must pass a hashtable with prefix-to-URI mappings to the `-Namespace` parameter, and use these prefixes in the query when referring to elements - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49387055/45375) for more information.
- By contrast, if you use PowerShell's XML DOM adaption (property-based access), namespace declarations and namespace prefixes in element names are *ignored*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Apart from your code not trying to filter by `field_name="Test2"` (which may not be necessary if the `id` values are unique across the entire document), your problem was the use of the `.item` property on the *array*-valued parent property, `.items`:

**Because `.items` is an *array* and arrays have a *type-native* [`.Item` member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-item#System_Array_System_Collections_IList_Item_System_Int32_)**<sup>[1]</sup>, that member takes precedence over [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375) (where attributes and child elements appear *as if* they were properties), so that **the child XML elements named `item` are no longer directly accessible with `.item`**.

**Explicit enumeration of the array elements (which are XML elements in this case) - via `.ForEach({ $_.item })`<sup>[2]</sup> - bypasses the problem**, and accessing the `.item` property on each [`[XmlElement]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) then works as intended.

Note: `XmlElements` too have a type-native [`.Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement.Item) property, but in the context of PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM the logic is *reversed*: it is the *adapted* properties that take precedence over the type-native ones (the latter can be accessed as *methods* with a `get_` prefix; e.g., `.get_Item()`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621547/45375) for an example with an adapted `.Name` property (from a child element or attribute) shadowing the element's type-native one.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, the parameterized `.Item` property is exposed via an *interface* (`IList`), but PowerShell surfaces such explicit-interface-implementation properties as if they were direct properties of a type.</sup>

<sup>[2] Ideally, you'd be able to use `.ForEach('item')` as a faster alternative, but as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2 this doesn't work due to a *bug*, detailed in [GitHub issue #15994](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15994).</sup>