# How to get xml field value using csv column header powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, command-line-interface

When I use for loop and then add value $b here in code **({ $_.'field_name' -eq  $b}** then it's giving blank value instead of result.

```
$CSVpath = "G:\1.csv"
$columncount=((Get-Content $CSVpath)[0] -split ",").count
write-host $columncount
$xml= "G:\1.xml"
[xml] $xmlDoc = Get-Content $xml
for($i=0; $i -le $columncount;$i++){
$a = ((Get-Content $CSVpath)[0] -split(','))[$i]
$b= "'$a'"
Function xml{
param($value)
$xml= "G:\1.xml"
[xml] $xmlDoc = Get-Content $xml
$a1= $xmlDoc.enum_types.enum_type.Where({ $_.'field_name' -eq  $b}, 'First').items.item.where({ $_.id -eq 1}).value
$d = $a1.'#cdata-section'
write-host  $d
}
xml $b
}
```

Please help me to resolve issue.
Please find xml:

```
    <enum_types>
    
        <enum_type field_name="Test1">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <value>A</value>
                </item>
            </items>
            </enum_type>
<enum_type field_name="Test2">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <value>A</value>
                </item>
            </items>
            </enum_type>
        </enum_types>
```

Please find csv file : [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a streamlined version of your code:

```sh
$CSVpath = "G:\1.csv"
$xmlPath = "G:\1.xml"

# This is a more robust (and faster) way to load XML files.
($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path $xmlPath))

# Get all column names
$columnNames = (Get-Content -First 1 $CSVpath) -split ',' -replace '"'
Write-Host "Column count: $($columnNames.Count); names: $columnNames"

foreach ($columnName in $columnNames) {
  @($xmlDoc.enum_types.enum_type.Where({ $_.field_name -eq $columnName }, 'First').
   items).ForEach({ $_.item }).Where({ $_.id -eq 1 }).value
}
```

It outputs the following for me:

```
Column count: 2; names: Test1 Test2
A
A
```

Note:

- Since there are no CDATA sections in your XML document, there is no need for `.'#cdata-section'`
- The rationale for using `.ForEach()` to enumerate the child elements named `<item>`, specifically - while not strictly necessary with your sample XML document, since there's only *one* such child element - is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68884190/45375).

  - Use of `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), in order to apply [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) (and `.Where()`) safely is only required in *Windows PowerShell*, due to an unfortunate bug<sup>[1]</sup>, which has since been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+.
  - The linked answer also shows a - faster - XPath-based solution, via [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml), which you could apply analogously to an `[xml]` instance already in memory (`$xmlDoc` in this case), via its [`.SelectSingleNode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode) instance method.

---

The above only operates on the *column names* of the CSV file, with a *hard-coded* `id` value - as in your own attempt.

To **extract data from the XML based on the *data* in the CSV and based on which columns are filled in**:

```sh
$CSVpath = "G:\1.csv"
$xmlPath = "G:\1.xml"

# This is a more robust (and faster) way to load XML files.
($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path $xmlPath))

# Import the CSV.
$csvRows = Import-Csv $CSVpath
# Get the column names.
$columnNames = $csvRows[0].psobject.Properties.Name

foreach ($csvRow in $csvRows) {
  foreach ($columnName in $columnNames) {
    $id = $csvRow.$columnName
    if (-not $id) { continue }
    @($xmlDoc.enum_types.enum_type.Where({ $_.field_name -eq $columnName }, 'First').
      items).ForEach({ $_.item }).Where({ $_.id -eq $id }).value
  }
}
```

Note: With a nested loop like that it's definitely worth considering switching to an XPath solution with `.SelectSingleNode()` in order to improve performance.

<sup>[1] `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` should work on *any* object, even *scalar* (non-collection) ones, but in Windows PowerShell that doesn't work with certain types, such as XML elements.</sup>