# set_item method is not in object but it works

Tags: powershell

after creating a hashtable with PowerShell I discovered a method: set_item() which works perfectly, but there is nor such method in this PowerShell object and neither in .NET class hashtable documentation?

```
$usa = @{ CA = "California" ; NY = "New York" ; "IL" = "Illinois" ; "NH" = "New 
Hampshire" }
$usa.GetType() # as expected a hashtable
$usa | Get-Member # no method set_item
$usa.set_item("NY","State") # it works perfectly
$usa
```

Comment: Append `-Force` to the `Get-Member` cmdlet. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23640335/9898643)